# Why "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" is normally used for login but not for registration?

Tags: authentication, web-application, api, rest

I may be wrong, but for security reasons, in REST APIs the login credentials are always sent with the content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. But I haven't seen the same with user registration; the data is normally sent as JSON. Why wouldn't you use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for both registration and login? I'm missing something?

Comment: There are no security reasons behind this and I don't know what your observation is based on (i.e. anecdotal evidence vs. systematic research). Note that `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is the default type used in HTML form, so what you saw might be due do some compatibility requirement between REST API based access and login using HTML form.

Comment: Read carefully the name of the content type... it explicitly mentions **form**. all applications that simply have an HTML form and a `submit` input will automatically use that content type by default. Sure, you can avoid using a `submit` and instead use javascript to make the HTTP request but that is more work and renders the login page unusable if javascript is disabled, so there are not many pros and some cons which means most people end up using that content type for login but not all the stuff handled by JS-triggered requests